# How can I disable Fakes.exe running when I break into debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging, microsoft-fakes

I have recently started creating some tests in a solution which make use of the Microsoft Fakes framework. All good there, however I've now noticed that when I am debugging my main program (not the tests themselves) and break into the debugger, I have to wait a considerable time.

When I look at Process Explorer I see Fakes.exe running;

```
"C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Fakes\fakes.exe" @D:\some\path\My.Tests\obj\Debug\Fakes\fakes.args
```

Any idea why this is happening when I debug the main program, and how I can prevent it?

Comment: How are the projects set up?  Does it get launched when only the main program is run (not with unit tests previously)?  I haven't had issues as long as project of the main program had no dependencies with the unit test projects.

Comment: The unit tests project has dependencies on the main program, (for which I have fakes assemblies generated) but not the other way around. I don't know why fakes.exe would be running here, except to rebuild the fakes assemblies when the main program changes. But kicking it off when I break into the  debugger is curious...